# meta_query, how to search using both relation OR & AND?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, meta-query

Resolved: See answer below.

---

I have a custom post type called *BOOKS*. It has several custom fields, named: `TITLE`, `AUTHOR`, `GENRE`, `RATING`. How do I fix my `meta_query` code below so that only *books* that have the search word in the custom fields: `title`, `author`, `genre` **WITH EXACTLY** the `rating` specified in my search form, gets displayed in the results?

I have made a custom search form; a text area that will search through the `title`, `author` and `genre`; and a dropdown that will search for the `rating`. The `meta_query` I made below only searches through the `title`, `author`, and `genre`. But I am now stumped in how to add the code for the `rating`.

This is how I visually imagined it with meta_query relation: 
(title OR author OR genre) AND rating

```
$args = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
             'key' => 'title',
             'value' => $searchvalue,
             'compare' => 'LIKE'
          );
          array(
             'key' => 'author',
             'value' => $searchvalue,
             'compare' => 'LIKE'
          );
          array(
             'key' => 'genre',
             'value' => $searchvalue,
             'compare' => 'LIKE'
          );
), 
        array(
        'relation' => 'AND', 
          array(
             'key' => 'rating',
             'value' => $ratingvalue,
             'compare' => '=',
             'type' => 'NUMERIC'
          ));
```

I would extremely appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: please see the link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35683/meta-query-with-and-or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thanks! So if I can't do it with meta_query, is there another way how I can do it?

Comment: some example define on a last on this link. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found the solution with some help.
The code below worked perfectly.

```
    $args => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'title',
                'value' => $searchvalue,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'author',
                'value' => $searchvalue,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'genre',
                'value' => $searchvalue,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'value' => $ratingvalue,
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'

        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This shouldn't work – it isn't supported by WP_Meta_Query. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75079/nested-meta-query-with-multiple-relation-keys

Comment: Yes, it is actually not working. Need a permanent solution to for using both relation. This is very needy.

Comment: In WP 4.1, nested meta queries like this answer should now work, more info here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/

Comment: @Angelica Santibanez digging up an old topic I know but is this officially supported now? I am struggling to get this working and hope you can help!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to an old answer: now it is clearly supported and explained in the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query

Answer (score 6):

After a bit trial and error I find a solution to this. This is logical I mean meta_query does not supports the array for field "key", but giving the array in "key", I'm getting the perfect solution. I may be sound crazy but it's working like charm.

```
$args => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => array('title','author','genre',),
        'value' => $searchvalue,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'rating',
        'value' => $ratingvalue,
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'

    )
)
```

You only get a warning for "trim()" as we are passing an array instead of a string. Suppress that warning or Please add something if you find a better solution.

Comment: I was using this key => array() hack, however in WP 4.1 it appears to no longer be 'unofficially' supported. Fortunately the 4.1 updates to meta_query now allow the chosen answer to work properly.